# about split command in string using vb.net

Tags: url, query-string

am having url  .it contain the querstring value like this.to split the url and store the querystring values in an array .query string values are not passed with in application . 
it comes from another application

```
url
----
http://.....?lead_id=152818&vendor_id=100001&list_id=1001&gmt_offset_now=0.00&phone_code=91&phone_number=9942321400&title=MR&first_name=Hari&middle_initial=Q&last_name=PUBLIC&address1=249+MUNDON+ROAD&address2=MALDON&address3=FL&city=44&state=TN&province=NO_PROVINCE&postal_code=600004&country_code=IN&gender=M&date_of_birth=0000-00-00&alt_phone=9942321400&email=test@test.com&security_phrase=nothing&comments=COMMENTS&user=22222&pass=test&campaign=OUTBOUND&phone_login=22222&original_phone_login=22222&phone_pass=test&fronter=22222&closer=22222&group=OUTBOUND&channel_group=OUTBOUND&SQLdate=2012-08-07+164931&epoch=1344338372&uniqueid=1344338352.12754&customer_zap_channel=&customer_server_ip=&server_ip=10.103.200.177&SIPexten=22222&session_id=8600062&phone=9942321400&parked_by=152818&dispo=N&dialed_number=9942321400&dialed_label=MAIN&source_id=10001&rank=1&owner=Southeast&camp_script=&in_script=&script_width=600&script_height=340&fullname=J.Hariharan&recording_filename=OUTBOUND_20120807-164911_22222_9942321400&recording_id=248601&user_custom_one=&user_custom_two=&user_custom_three=&user_custom_four=&user_custom_five=&preset_number_a=&preset_number_b=&preset_number_c=&preset_number_d=&preset_number_e=&preset_dtmf_a=&preset_dtmf_b=&session_name=1344338181_2222216466857"



my question is i want to store the querystring values in an one dimensional string 
array.


my code
-------
Dim strarr() As String
    Dim s As String = "http://...../test.aspx?lead_id=152818&vendor_id=100001&list_id=1001&gmt_offset_now=0.00&phone_code=91&phone_number=9942321400&title=MR&first_name=Hari&middle_initial=Q&last_name=PUBLIC&address1=249+MUNDON+ROAD&address2=MALDON&address3=FL&city=44&state=TN&province=NO_PROVINCE&postal_code=600004&country_code=IN&gender=M&date_of_birth=0000-00-00&alt_phone=9942321400&email=test@test.com&security_phrase=nothing&comments=COMMENTS&user=22222&pass=test&campaign=OUTBOUND&phone_login=22222&original_phone_login=22222&phone_pass=test&fronter=22222&closer=22222&group=OUTBOUND&channel_group=OUTBOUND&SQLdate=2012-08-07+164931&epoch=1344338372&uniqueid=1344338352.12754&customer_zap_channel=&customer_server_ip=&server_ip=10.103.200.177&SIPexten=22222&session_id=8600062&phone=9942321400&parked_by=152818&dispo=N&dialed_number=9942321400&dialed_label=MAIN&source_id=10001&rank=1&owner=Southeast&camp_script=&in_script=&script_width=600&script_height=340&fullname=J.Hariharan&recording_filename=OUTBOUND_20120807-164911_22222_9942321400&recording_id=248601&user_custom_one=&user_custom_two=&user_custom_three=&user_custom_four=&user_custom_five=&preset_number_a=&preset_number_b=&preset_number_c=&preset_number_d=&preset_number_e=&preset_dtmf_a=&preset_dtmf_b=&session_name=1344338181_2222216466857"
    strarr = s.Split("?")
    Dim s1 As String = strarr(1)
    Dim constr() As String
    constr = s1.Split("&")


but am not get correct result


my result
---------
list_id=1001
gmt_offset_now=0.00
phone_code=91
phone_number=9942321400


expected result
---------------
  1001
  0.00
  91
  9942321400
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your 'constr' and use one more split ( by '=' ). Results can be stored in List(of String).

```
dim r as new list(of String)
for each c in constr
   r.add(c.split("=")(1))
next
```

(something like this)

To view this you should list all items inside 'r', so you'll need another for.

```
for each item in r
   console.writeline(item)
next
```

You can do it inside first loop either.

Comment: Kuczynski am getting error in dim statement. like type"list" is not defined

Comment: @Kuczynski i correct it . but i don't know how to view the result